# SQL Query - select data from table A based on two fields in table B

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
A:
[ date,
 step,
 status,
 ... ]

B:
[ date,
  step,
  name,
  ... ]
```

I want to get result in form of

```
[date, step, name]
```

based on status parameter. I can easly get data from table A using following query:

```
Select date, step From A Where status='1'
```

and the result would be like:

```
1. 2010-09-12; 5
2. 2010-09-13; 3
...
```

but i dont know how to use it to find names from table B corresponding to those records.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select B.Name
From A
Inner Join B
  On A.date = B.date
  And A.step = B.step
Where A.status = '1'
```

Comment: Thought i Post a link to joins because it seems he doesn't know what those are: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks for link. I know basic of join but i didnt know that you can do it based on more than one condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables. From your question i immagine that you want to do something like this:

```
Select a.date, a.step, b.name  
From A a, B b
Where a.status='1' and a.date = b.date and a.step = b.step
```

You can read mor on joining table in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) or [this](http://www.halfgaar.net/sql-joins-are-easy) description of sql joins